# Trouble getting Authorization Code Scopes from Uber (DRIVER APIs)

Tags: authorization, driver, uber-api, scopes

I'm trying to get access to Uber's DRIVERS API's and it has been days without any solution. I tried to contact all types of departments from Uber, and still no access. Perhaps anyone know how I can get access to their Driver API's?

Contacting the company through email and phone.

Comment: Unfortunately, customer support questions like this are off-topic for Stack Overflow, which is a forum for programming questions. For why, see [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576), [Questions about licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745).  I think only Uber customer support can help here.